# ReactJS with Array of Objects (searching character by character)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Stackoverflow and ReactJS as well. I have the following code with 'array of objects' using a "textField" to filter 'array of objects'.

```
import React from 'react';
import NameItem from "./component/NameItem";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { term: '', names = [{ name: 'Roony', about: 'He is a student'},{ name: 'Rocky', about: 'He is a player'},{ name: 'Ronny', about: 'He is a singer'}], filteredData:[{}] };
}
    renderData(filteredData) {
        if(filteredData) {
            this.setState({names: filteredData});
        }
        return filteredData.map(item => <NameItem item={item}></NameItem>);

    }

    filterNames(namePass) {
       const names = [{ name: 'Roony', about: 'He is a student'},{ name: 'Rocky', about: 'He is a player'},{ name: 'Ronny', about: 'He is a singer'}];
        if(namePass && names) {
            let filteredData = names.filter((item) => {
               return  item.toLowerCase().startsWith(namePass.toLowerCase())
            });
            console.log(filteredData);
            this.setState({filteredData: filteredData});
            if (filteredData) {
                this.renderData(filteredData);
            }
            if (namePass === '') {
                this.target(names);
            }
        }
        }
        render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <label>Search Person: </label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.name} id="searchEmp"
                           placeholder="Enter Person's Name"
                           onChange={(event) => {
                               this.setState({term: event.target.value});
                               // console.log(event.target.value);
                               this.filterNames(event.target.value);
                           }}/><br/>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <NameItem item={this.state.names}></NameItem>
                    {
                    }
                </ul>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I want result like when I start entering a character (for e.g I enter 'R') in "textField", all names starting from 'R' should get appear **with all details** and vice versa. A little more I want to set a whitespace as a invalid input when entered and then redirect to a window asking a user for input. I tried but as a beginner I'm getting error(s) one after another.

How can I filter this 'array of objects' to get my desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      term: '', 
      names : [
          { name: 'ARoony', about: 'He is a student'},
          { name: 'BRocky', about: 'He is a player'},
          { name: 'CRonny', about: 'He is a singer'}
        ], 
        filteredData:[{}] 
      };
    }


  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <label>Search Person: </label>
      <input 
      type="text" 
      value={this.state.name} 
      id="searchEmp"
      placeholder="Enter Person's Name"
      onChange={(event)=>this.setState({term: event.target.value})}
        />
                        <br/>      
      
      {this.state.names && this.state.names.filter(x=>x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.state.term)).map(item=>{
        
        return(<div className="data-body">
          <div>{item.name}</div>
          <div>{item.about}</div>          
          </div>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

}

export default App;
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sea-ebzoj)

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi-this worked fine when 'npm start' for first time. After this the game starts, I want to enter 'R' in "textField" and printed result(s) should get filtered on basis of the character entered in "textField" means for the first time, all 3 results should be seen but When I enter next character 'O' after 'R' then again all 3 results should be seen. Now I enters again 'O' means now "textField" contains 'ROO', this time only 1st result should be seen because name of 1st student is only containing 'ROO' not others. So only details of 1st student should be seen and so on. Do help pls.

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi-again its working fine. A little more I want to set a check for a 'space' when entered with an alert message and then   screen should be to as it was in when 'npm start' for first time. (asking a user to enter something) Apart, what's the scope of 'import "./styles.css";' and 'export class' in fist 4 lines. I mean are these mandatory to write or we can skid this?

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi-what's wrong in my code? am I making silly mistake(s) or not following the right path to code a program? As a new to React, I'm finding my code much complex when compared to the code of helpers, just like you. Even don't know what to import or not. So I'm getting stuck every single time when dealing with ReactJS by my own.

Comment: See DEMO again, no need styles.css in my code you can remove it.

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi-its containing 'space' but it should not be. After clicking on 'OK' of alert message the screen should get load with the original screen as it was before entering space. For now, its set to enter the next value after 'space' when clicked on 'OK' button of alert message. I hope I'm clear with my query.